# How to explain Visual Studio that my source code is in another directory?

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, dump

I'm doing dump analysis. Normally when I access a dump and double-click in the callstack, Visual Studio asks me where to find the mentioned file. That openfile dialogbox gives me information about the location (including the GIT hash) of my source code.

Unfortunately I've done something wrong, and now Visual Studio does not ask anything anymore: he just opens the source code file in some directory, even though that file is not the correct version.

I'd like to see that openfile dialog back.

For your information: I know it's possible to have that particular file received from GIT and have that file opened somewhere in the %TEMP% directory, but I don't want that: this only opens that one file, while I'd like to use the openfile dialogbox to retrieve my whole project from GIT.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you click Cancel on that dialog VS remembers your selection and won't spam you again for the file.  Right-click the Solution node in the Solution Explorer pane > Properties > Debug Source Files and delete the relevant entries in the "Do not look" box.

Comment: @HansPassant: There is indeed a line in the "Directories containing source code" part, but when I delete it, it keeps getting back. Is there a way to remove it permanently?

Comment: You are doing something wrong, I can't look over your shoulder to have a reasonable guess.  This info is preserved in a hidden file, filename extension .suo

Comment: Ah, indeed, I missed the "in some directory" cue.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the meantime I've found the answer: in Tools, Options, Debugging, General, there's a setting "Require source files to exactly match the original version". By accident, this has been unchecked. Checking it back again solves my issue: now Visual Studio is showing the openfile dialogbox again. For reference purposes, I'll put here the text of the openfile dialogbox:

> The source file is different from when the module was built.
>   Would you like the debugger to use it anyway?